# how to add widget into MVC .NET application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, widget, weather

I would like to add this widget into my MVC .NET application.

```
<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/new-york-ny/10007/weather-forecast/349727" class="aw-widget-legal"></a><div id="awcc1457986432640" class="aw-widget-current" data-locationkey="" data- unit="f" data-language="en-us" data-useip="true" data-uid="awcc1457986432640"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>
```

I copied this code from http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets/current and pasted it into my Contacts.cshtml view just to test it, but it doesn't make any difference. I don't get any error either, and all I get is a blank page.

Is there any specific way to add widgets to these type of projects?

I'm new to ASP.NET, MVC and also to this website. I am sorry if I sound slow right now.

Comment: Try using Firebug in firefox to investigate the network requests, and review the documentation to make sure it's implemented correctly.  MVC doesn't factor in here - but note, that if you  are local investigate if something needs to happen differently to setup your localhost environment.

Comment: I have tested the plugin with a simple html, it works for me, Can you also test it in a simple html page and see if that works? I would also suggest to use something like fiddler or network debugging in developer tools of the browser to see if something fails while load the site